# Rails link_to unable to get a confirmation dialog to appear

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get the link_to to be able to create a link with both options and html options.    I need to be able to add the  so I went with the method with the do.

My question is: How do I get this to work with the :confirmation.  As it is written, it is appending confirm to the url.  I would like to pass it in as a html option so it will pull up the dialog box.

Any ideas what I need to do to be able to get it to behave like that?

```
<li>
  <%= link_to :controller => "services", :action => "delete_results", :build => @id, :suite => @cookie_value, :confirm => "Are you sure?" do %>
  <i class="icon-trash"></i>
    Delete Results
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

url_options and html_options are separate attributes for link_to. You need to tell ruby that they are different parameters in your list

`link_to({:controller => "services", :action => "delete_results", :build => @id, :suite => @cookie_value}, {:confirm => "Are you sure?"})`

Wrapping of second hash in {} is optional, but simplifies reading

Comment: Awesome, thanks..  I swear I tried this but was getting a syntax error every way I tried.  But this works perfectly!!